# keep assoc array checkbox checked

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to keep a list of checkboxes checked until post is valid and no errors. Below is the code I'm  using. I would be thankful for any help.

```
     <?php foreach ($drinks_checkbox as $option => $options){  ?>

     <input type='checkbox' id='drinks[]' name='drinks[]' value='<?php echo $option;?>'   <?php if(!empty($_POST['drinks'])){if($_POST['drinks']==$option){ echo "checked='checked'" ; }}?> /><?php echo $options;?><br />
    <?php } ?>
```

I can successfully display the checked checkboxes using implode however I need help for the above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_POST['drinks'] is an array. Also, the id value does not need to be 'drinks[]'

Try something like this:

```
$drinksIndex = 0;
$drinksPost = $_POST['drinks'];
foreach ($drinks_checkbox as $option => $options){  ?>

  <input type='checkbox' id='drinks<?php echo $drinksIndex; ?>' name='drinks[<?php echo $drinksIndex; ?>]' value='<?php echo $option;?>'<?php
  if( !empty($drinksPost[$drinksIndex]) ) echo " checked='checked'";
  $drinksIndex++;
?> /><?php
echo $options;?><br />
<?php
} ?>
```

Amended the !empty($drinksPost[$drinksIndex]) part and changed to associative.

If this doesn't work, can you include $drinks_checkbox

Comment: Thanks! Works well if all checkboxes are checked however throws an error to the ones that are not checked.   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\easyform\register_form.php on line 133

Comment: Hmm yes - change count( $drinksPost ) to !empty( $drinksPost[$drinksIndex]) - I'll amend the above. If you're new here it's customary to vote the answer up if it's what you're after :)

Comment: Here is what happens, If I check all of the checkboxes  then they stay checked If I only check a few then only the first one stays checked.

Comment: Ah yes - the length of the array changes depending on how many are checked. The solution is to either have a <hidden> field for each option that has a default value, OR (better) set the field names as associative arrays. Amended above to reflect.

Comment: Thank you!  Perfect! I'm new to php can you explain what is going on please. I would like to understand the process more. Thank you once again.

Comment: When you name your checkboxes 'drinks[]' they are passed to PHP as a standard array - however, anything that isn't checked (and has no value) is NOT passed to the array. So if you only check one drink, the array will be say, array( 'martini' ) two (different) drinks array( 'cosmo', 'tom collins' ) - and each time their index will usually be different. By forcing the index in the HTML - name="drinks[1]" - we are making sure their index stays consistent.

Comment: So the drinks[1], 1 being the drinksIndex and so on... Thank you, checkboxes are FUN! You've been a great help.